# How to pass web driver instance to another class's method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to pass a Selenium web driver instance from Master.java to Child.java but I am getting a null pointer exception on line 9 in Child.java. Adding extends to the class should allow me to access the variables in Master, but it does not.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
    at Child.someMethod(Child.java:9)
    at Master.main(Master.java:28)
```

Master.java

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Master {

  public WebDriver driver; 

  public void launchBrowser() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
  }

    public void gotoPage() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.quit();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
        Master m = new Master();
        Child c = new Child();

        m.launchBrowser();
        m.gotoPage();
        c.someMethod();
        m.closeBrowser();
    }

}
```

Child.java

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Child extends Master {

    public void someMethod() throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `someMethod()` with a `Driver driver` parameter and in the master pass the driver in the method call.

Child.java

```
  public void someMethod(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    }
```

Master.java

```
  Master m = new Master();
        Child c = new Child();

        m.launchBrowser();
        m.gotoPage();
        c.someMethod(driver);
        m.closeBrowser();
```

Although it does defeat the purpose of you using inheritance.

Comment: This works if I add "public static WebDriver driver;" to Master.java. However, this makes driver a global object. I wonder if there are better alternatives.

Comment: @Macs You're calling something in a static manner. Are you trying to call driver using `Master.driver` or `Child.driver`? Edit:Yea you don't really want to do that. Avoid `static` keyword as much as you can. How are you calling the driver? what's the line of code causing the error?

Comment: On line 28 of Master.java, I changed the line to "c.someMethod(m.driver);". In Child.java, I added "import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;" and also changed line 9 to "public void someMethod(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {". That fixes the static error and solves the null pointer exception.

Comment: You don't need the `m.` part. simply `c.someMethod(driver);` and have `someMethod(driver);` in Child.java

Comment: "c.someMethod(driver);" gives an error that says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field driver". "public void someMethod(driver) throws InterruptedException {" give an error that says "Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList".

Comment: Apologies. You're correct. use `c.someMethod(m.driver);`. I've tried the code provided, it executes fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to initialise child, you called launchBrowser() in main which initialises the driver, call launchBrowser() for the child object too

Comment: I tried calling launchBrowser from Child.java, but I get the same null pointer exception error.

```
public class Child extends Master {

    public void someMethod() throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
  }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
        Master m = new Master();
 
        m.launchBrowser();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I guess you might have solution already but this is what I am adding here for you. 
You can always invoke constructor on the child object to pass your driver from Master to Child. 



  public class Master {
          public WebDriver driver; 

          public void launchBrowser() {
              System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
          }

            public void gotoPage() {
                driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            }

            public void closeBrowser() {
                driver.quit();
            }


            public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
                Master m = new Master();
                Child c = new Child(m.driver); // THIS IS you passing driver of master 

                m.launchBrowser();
                m.gotoPage();
                c.someMethod();
                m.closeBrowser();        
            }
    }


    public class Child extends Master{
        public WebDriver driver; 
// below is your constructor  - setting Master driver here 
        public Child(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver=driver ;
        }
        public void someMethod() throws InterruptedException {
            // your code goes here
         // below driver will set up automatically for your method
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write out a solution. It is best if I can figure out how to use inheritance. However, when I ran the code, I got a null pointer exception in Child.java for "WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);"

Comment: (1) you are supposed to give this "chromedriver.exe" .. you not have ".EXE" at the end of System.setProperty (2) "WebDriverWait" is old and obsolete ..you can try other fluent wait or Thread sleep until you resolve your real issue